# how to copy elements from one map to another in freemarker

Tags: freemarker

For example If I have values like below in json
{
"ABC": {
"x": false,
"y": false,
"z": true
}
}

I want to make new map and copy values from ABC, how to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

FreeMarker assumes that maps won't change, and it provides no way to modify them. So there's no copying either, but of course you can assign a map to a variable. (Some may point out that you can actually add together maps with `+`, but that just creates a view, and doesn't modify an existing map.)

If you really need to modify/copy maps, then you will need to expose some Java methods for that. At least, you will need one that creates a new `Map` of the desired type (like `LinkedHashMap`). After that though, you can use the Java API-s via `?api`, like `myMap?api.putAll(otherMap)`.

Comment: Our requirement is that, we have to achieve thru Free Marker only, cant use Java. Thanks for reply.